# Set Request Not Working SNMP4j

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I have searched everywhere but I haven't found the solution to my problem.  I've tried all solutions involving changing the community name, certain different set classes and I still can't get the set to work for SNMP4j.  The code executes fine and can be accessed from iReasoning MIB browser but will not change the value of the OID after the set executes.  The SNMP classes and tester classes are below.

SNMPManager code:

```
public class SNMPManager {

Snmp snmp = null;
String address = null;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param add
 */
public SNMPManager(String add) {
    address = add;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /**
     * Port 161 is used for Read and Other operations Port 162 is used for the trap
     * generation
     */
    SNMPManager client = new SNMPManager("udp:127.0.0.1/161");
    client.start();
    /**
     * OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 => SysDec OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 => SysName => MIB
     * explorer will be usefull here, as discussed in previous article
     */
    String sysDescr = client.getAsString(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"));
    System.out.println(sysDescr);
}

/**
 * Start the Snmp session. If you forget the listen() method you will not get
 * any answers because the communication is asynchronous and the listen() method
 * listens for answers.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void start() throws IOException {
    TransportMapping<?> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    snmp = new Snmp(transport);
    // Do not forget this line!
    transport.listen();
}

/**
 * Method which takes a single OID and returns the response from the agent as a
 * String.
 * 
 * @param oid
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String getAsString(OID oid) throws IOException {
    ResponseEvent event = get(new OID[] { oid });
    return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
}

/**
 * This method is capable of handling multiple OIDs
 * 
 * @param oids
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public ResponseEvent get(OID oids[]) throws IOException {
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    for (OID oid : oids) {
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
    }
    pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
    ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, getTarget(), null);
    if (event != null) {
        return event;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("GET timed out");
}

public ResponseEvent set(OID oid, String val) throws IOException {
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    VariableBinding varBind = new VariableBinding(oid, new OctetString(val));
    pdu.add(varBind);
    pdu.setType(PDU.SET);
    //pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(1));
    Target target = getTarget();

    ResponseEvent event = snmp.set(pdu, target);
    if (event != null) {
        System.out.println("\nResponse:\nGot Snmp Set Response from Agent");
        System.out.println("Snmp Set Request = " + event.getRequest().getVariableBindings());
        PDU responsePDU = event.getResponse();
        System.out.println("\nresponsePDU = " + responsePDU);
        if (responsePDU != null) {
            int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
            int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
            String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();
            System.out.println("\nresponsePDU = " + responsePDU);
            if (errorStatus == PDU.noError) {
                System.out.println("Snmp Set Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
            } else {
                System.out.println("errorStatus = " + responsePDU);
                System.out.println("Error: Request Failed");
                System.out.println("Error Status = " + errorStatus);
                System.out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
                System.out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
            }
        }

        return event;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("SET timed out");
}

/**
 * This method returns a Target, which contains information about where the data
 * should be fetched and how.
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Target getTarget() {
    Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
    target.setAddress(targetAddress);
    target.setRetries(2);
    target.setTimeout(1500);
    target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
    return target;
}
}
```

SNMPAgent code:

```
public class SNMPAgent extends BaseAgent {

private String address;

/**
 *
 * @param address
 * @throws IOException
 */
public SNMPAgent(String address) throws IOException {

    /**
     * Creates a base agent with boot-counter, config file, and a CommandProcessor
     * for processing SNMP requests. Parameters: "bootCounterFile" - a file with
     * serialized boot-counter information (read/write). If the file does not exist
     * it is created on shutdown of the agent. "configFile" - a file with serialized
     * configuration information (read/write). If the file does not exist it is
     * created on shutdown of the agent. "commandProcessor" - the CommandProcessor
     * instance that handles the SNMP requests.
     */
    super(new File("conf.agent"), new File("bootCounter.agent"),
            new CommandProcessor(new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID())));
    this.address = address;
}

/**
 * Adds community to security name mappings needed for SNMPv1 and SNMPv2c.
 */
@Override
protected void addCommunities(SnmpCommunityMIB communityMIB) {
    Variable[] com2sec = new Variable[] { new OctetString("public"), new OctetString("cpublic"), // security name
            getAgent().getContextEngineID(), // local engine ID
            new OctetString("public"), // default context name
            new OctetString(), // transport tag
            new Integer32(StorageType.nonVolatile), // storage type
            new Integer32(RowStatus.active) // row status
    };
    MOTableRow<?> row = communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry()
            .createRow(new OctetString("public2public").toSubIndex(true), com2sec);
    communityMIB.getSnmpCommunityEntry().addRow((SnmpCommunityEntryRow) row);

}

/**
 * Adds initial notification targets and filters.
 */
@Override
protected void addNotificationTargets(SnmpTargetMIB arg0, SnmpNotificationMIB arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Adds all the necessary initial users to the USM.
 */
@Override
protected void addUsmUser(USM arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Adds initial VACM configuration.
 */
@Override
protected void addViews(VacmMIB vacm) {
    vacm.addGroup(SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_SNMPv2c, new OctetString("cpublic"), new OctetString("v1v2group"),
            StorageType.nonVolatile);

    vacm.addAccess(new OctetString("v1v2group"), new OctetString("public"), SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_ANY,
            SecurityLevel.NOAUTH_NOPRIV, MutableVACM.VACM_MATCH_EXACT, new OctetString("fullReadView"),
            new OctetString("fullWriteView"), new OctetString("fullNotifyView"), StorageType.nonVolatile);

    vacm.addViewTreeFamily(new OctetString("fullReadView"), new OID("1.3"), new OctetString(),
            VacmMIB.vacmViewIncluded, StorageType.nonVolatile);


}

/**
 * Unregister the basic MIB modules from the agent's MOServer.
 */
@Override
protected void unregisterManagedObjects() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Register additional managed objects at the agent's server.
 */
@Override
protected void registerManagedObjects() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void initTransportMappings() throws IOException {
    transportMappings = new TransportMapping[1];
    Address addr = GenericAddress.parse(address);
    TransportMapping<?> tm = TransportMappings.getInstance().createTransportMapping(addr);
    transportMappings[0] = tm;
}

/**
 * Start method invokes some initialization methods needed to start the agent
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void start() throws IOException {

    init();
    // This method reads some old config from a file and causes
    // unexpected behavior.
    // loadConfig(ImportModes.REPLACE_CREATE);
    addShutdownHook();
    getServer().addContext(new OctetString("public"));
    finishInit();
    run();
    sendColdStartNotification();
}

/**
 * Clients can register the MO they need
 */
public void registerManagedObject(ManagedObject mo) {
    try {
        server.register(mo, null);
    } catch (DuplicateRegistrationException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

public void unregisterManagedObject(MOGroup moGroup) {
    moGroup.unregisterMOs(server, getContext(moGroup));
}

}
```

MOCreator code:

```
public class MOCreator {
public static MOScalar<Variable> createReadOnly(OID oid,Object value ){
    return new MOScalar<Variable>(oid,
            MOAccessImpl.ACCESS_READ_WRITE,
            getVariable(value));
}

private static Variable getVariable(Object value) {
    if(value instanceof String) {
        return new OctetString((String)value);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmanaged Type: " + value.getClass());
}

}
```

Tester class:

```
public class TestSNMPAgent {
String siteOIDNumber = "1";
String dataOIDNumber = "1";
String sensorOIDNumber = "1";
OID newOIDdata = new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.5." + siteOIDNumber + ".2." + dataOIDNumber + "." + sensorOIDNumber + ".0");
OID newOIDdata2 = new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.5.1.2.1.2.0");
OID newOIDdata3 = new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.5.1.2.1.3.0");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TestSNMPAgent client = new TestSNMPAgent("udp:127.0.0.1/161");
    client.init();
}

SNMPAgent agent = null;
/**
 * This is the client which we have created earlier
 */
SNMPManager client = null;

String address = null;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param add
 */
public TestSNMPAgent(String add) {
    address = add;
}

/**
 * Initiates the testing of the SNMP Agent.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void init() throws IOException {
    /*agent = new SNMPAgent("172.21.1.103/2001");*/
    agent = new SNMPAgent("172.21.1.103/2010");
    agent.start();

    // Since BaseAgent registers some MIBs by default we need to unregister
    // one before we register our own sysDescr. Normally you would
    // override that method and register the MIBs that you need
    agent.unregisterManagedObject(agent.getSnmpv2MIB());
    //agent.registerManagedObject(MOCreator.createReadOnly(sysDescr,"This Description is set By KGrewe"));
    agent.registerManagedObject(MOCreator.createReadOnly(newOIDdata, "50"));
    agent.registerManagedObject(MOCreator.createReadOnly(newOIDdata2, "NaN"));
    agent.registerManagedObject(MOCreator.createReadOnly(newOIDdata3, "3"));
    SNMPManager client1 = new SNMPManager("udp:127.21.1.103/2010");
    client1.start();
    client1.set(newOIDdata, "30");
    //System.out.println(newOIDdata);
    // Get back Value which is set
    //System.out.println(client1.getAsString(newOIDdata));
    while(true) {

    }

}

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I see that I put the wrong IP at the bottom but that doesn't fix the issue.  The error is no access.

Comment: all I needed was to add rwcommunity public at the bottom of snmpd.conf.

Comment: I have the exact same error. I am using Windows. Where do I find snmpd.conf?